# sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo -j2 or -j4 or -j1

Tags: ros, catkin-make, memory, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I tried many times to run catkin_make on raspberry PI by using this command : sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo -j2 or -j4 or -j1. But every time it gives this error

==> Processing catkin package: 'turtlesim'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh'
==> cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/turtlesim -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/turtlesim'
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/turtlesim
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/turtlesim/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.18
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1316 (message):
Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/turtlesim/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/turtlesim/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'turtlesim':
Command '['/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/turtlesim', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/turtlesim && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/turtlesim -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'

I am new on raspberry pi as well as ROS. I hope you all help me to move forward on raspberry pi...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243985/sudo-./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated---install--dcmake_build_type=release---install-space-/opt/ros/indigo--j2-or--j4-or--j1/) by [krishna890227](https://answers.ros.org/users/27376/krishna890227/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-19**:
Please change your question title to something that is actually a question / describes your problem. As it is right now it's not very informative / descriptive.

Additionally: could you please format your console copy/paste using the *Preformatted text* button (the one with `101010` on it). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install QT4 sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2016-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1